# Getting a USB network adapter working on a Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi zero that is using a wired network adapter via the USB port. My interfaces file seems to be configured to use the wireless adapter via `wpa_supplicant`.

How can I configure the system to use my wired adapter? I've seen some reference to configuring `eth0`, but I don't see that interface in the list from `ip link show`.

Is there something I'm supposed to do to get `eth0` installed?

Comment: What do you get back when you run `ifconfig`?

Comment: `eth0` would be an ethernet interface and it's not always named that. On my laptop it is `enp0s25`. Your wifi interface should be there when you ran `ip link show`. Mine is called `wlo1` but I've also seen `wlan1`.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , [please edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/405094/edit) by adding the output of `lsusb`

Comment: lsusb gave the video out, a keyboard, and two usb hubs - none of which are the ethernet adapter. I think the answer is that I need to get that ethernet adapter recognized by the pi.

Comment: What is the exact model of your USB adapter ?

Comment: It is a Chromecast Ethernet adapter, model EA4C0-1A. Several articles indicated that it worked great out of the box, but I must be paying for bad code I've written elsewhere.

Comment: https://store.google.com/product/ethernet_adapter_for_chromecast